# How can the value go from the Child element to the sister Element in React | JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-dom

I am taking a date from the drop down date picker and trying to use it in another page so I can cross reference times open for bookings. When the Datepicker selects a date, and The props value is set on the Btnsearch It tries to redirect and seems like it does rerender but the prop value is undefined while the wasSubmit changes to true. Where do I pull this prop from?

I have added what I thought was a router, I set the sate with an attribute `this.state.value` but that does not seem to fix the issue.

Here is my Date Picker, Btnsearch, Bookingpage

```
import "./Btnsearch/Btnsearch";
// react plugin used to create datetimepicker
import ReactDatetime from "react-datetime";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Bookingpage from "./Bookingpage/Bookingpage";

// reactstrap components
import {
  FormGroup,
  InputGroupAddon,
  InputGroupText,
  InputGroup,
  Col,
  Row
} from "reactstrap";
import Btnsearch from "./Btnsearch/Btnsearch";
class Datepicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
    //this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({wasSubmitted: true});
}

render() {
    const { value, wasSubmitted } = this.state;

    if (wasSubmitted) {
        return <Bookingpage><Redirect value={this.state.value} to='./Bookingpage/Bookingpage' /></Bookingpage>
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <FormGroup>
            <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                <InputGroupText
                >
                  <i className="ni ni-calendar-grid-58" />
                </InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
              <ReactDatetime
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              inputProps={{
                placeholder: "Date Picker Here"
              }}
              timeFormat={false}
              />
            </InputGroup>
          </FormGroup>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Btnsearch  type="submit" value={this.state.value}/>
          </form>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Datepicker;
```

```
import '../Datepicker';

class Btnsearch extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <button onClick={() => console.log(this.props.value)} className="btn btn-success search-card-btn">Search</button>
    );
    }
};

export default Btnsearch;
```

```
import '../Datepicker';
class Bookingpage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="bookingPage">
            <h1>{this.props.value}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Bookingpage;
```

When Select the date and hit the search btn I expect it to redirect to a page Bookingpage that says the value selected. The Actual results are

```html
    <div class="App">
        <div class="card freesearch-option">
            <label><span class="searchTitleTxt">Search For Availability</span>
                <div class="bookingPage">
                    <h1></h1></div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
State
value:
""

wasSubmitted: true
```

The full project is here https://react-puh2oq.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a handleChange function.

So it seems like you are picking a date but not `.setState()`ing the `this.state.value`.

```
            <ReactDatetime
              value={this.state.value}
// HERE YOU CALL IT, BUT handleChange DOESN'T EXIST.
              onChange={this.handleChange} 
              inputProps={{
                placeholder: "Date Picker Here"
              }}
              timeFormat={false}
             />
```

Well, a proper handleChange function could be like this:

```
.
.
.
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({wasSubmitted: true});
}

handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
}


render() {
    const { value, wasSubmitted } = this.state;

    if (wasSubmitted) {
        return <Bookingpage><Redirect value={this.state.value} to='./Bookingpage/Bookingpage' /></Bookingpage>
    } else {
.
.
.
```

- You don't have to .bind() neither this function nor `handleSubmit` as long as you use fat arrow syntax.

Comment: I was told to remove it last time, can you show me what it would look like corrected?

Comment: when I run this it says handleChange undefined

Comment: Can you please add it to the code at it would be for it to run

Comment: Check out the new edit. Place it right under `handleSubmit` and before `render()`, in the class body.

Comment: e.preventDefault is not a function is the error I get now

Comment: It is not `e.preventDefault` it is `e.preventDefault()` incase you are omitting the parathesis. Actually, you don't even have to use that line. However, I don't think that is the problem. Please check out the documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html and the docs for ReactDatetime.

Comment: I left a stackblitz one answer said I needed to import the babel the a babel plugin to handle binding that way. could you get my epexted out come with stack blitz https://react-puh2oq.stackblitz.io